# How to sort text by section and also sort lines under the section in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, text-manipulation

I have a text config file which is like this:

```
config server 'server'
        option url 'https://chef.libremesh.org'

config client 'client'
        option upgrade_packages '1'
        option auto_search '0'
        option advanced_mode '0'
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
config client 'client'
        option advanced_mode '0'
        option auto_search '0'
        option upgrade_packages '1'

config server 'server'
        option url 'https://chef.libremesh.org'
```

Which command to use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My perl is a bit rusty, so this can certainly be made cleaner.  Try:

```
perl -nE 'BEGIN{$/=""}; @b = split "\n", $_; 
    @a = shift @b; push @a, sort @b; 
    push @f, join("\n", @a); END{ say "$_\n" foreach sort @f }' input
```

Set $/ to the empty string so that perl reads each section as a record.  The initial `split` splits each record on the newlines, and then we construct the array @a by shifting off the first line of the section and then sorting the remaining lines.  Construct a string from that and push it onto the array @f.  At the end, sort the sections and write output.

You can trim a bit by autosplitting:

```
perl -F'\n' -a -nE 'BEGIN{$/=""}; 
    push @f, join "\n", shift @F, sort @F;
    END{ say "$_\n" foreach sort @f } ' input
```

or:

```
perl -00 -F'\n' -a -nE 'push @f, join "\n", shift @F, sort @F} 
    {print join "\n\n", sort @f' input
```

The last command is a somewhat weird idiom which takes advantage of the fact that `-n` puts the command inside an implicit `while(<>){...}` construct and the first `}` in the code matches the implicit `{` while the "unmatched" `{` matches the implicit `}`, making it similar to running the final code in an END block.

Comment: This works great. But it removes the empty lines at the beginning, ending and between the sections. Is it possible to do it without removing the empty lines ?

Comment: Ah, yes, those are important.  Will fix.

Comment: I think you can get what you need by just doing `say "$_\n"` to add an extra newline after each record.